# How To use Fixed set of colors for the Graph in MIMChart Library? suggestions are appreciable

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am having trouble with the MIMChart library to set the fixed set of colours. I am using Ritu Raj MIMChart library

```
MIMBarGraph *myBarChart;
myBarChart=[[MIMBarGraph alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 20, myTableView.frame.size.width-    50, myTableView.frame.size.width * 0.5)];
myBarChart.delegate=self;
myBarChart.tag=10+indexPath.row;
myBarChart.isGradient=YES;
myBarChart.groupedBars=YES;
myBarChart.glossStyle=GLOSS_STYLE_1;
myBarChart.xTitleStyle=X_TITLES_STYLE2;
[myBarChart drawBarChart];
[cell.contentView addSubview:myBarChart];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Delegate

```
-(NSArray *)colorsForBarChart:(id)graph {
    NSArray *colorsArray;

    MIMColorClass *color1=[MIMColorClass colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f Green:255.0f/255.0f Blue:127.0f/255.0f Alpha:1];
    MIMColorClass *color2=[MIMColorClass colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f Green:4.0f/255.0f Blue:0.0f/255.0f Alpha:1];
    MIMColorClass *color3=[MIMColorClass colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f Green:182.0f/255.0f Blue:193.0f/255.0f Alpha:1];
    MIMColorClass *color4=[MIMColorClass colorWithRed:1.0f/255.0f Green:255.0f/255.0f Blue:255.0f/255.0f Alpha:1];

    colorsArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:color1,color2,color3,color4, nil];

    return colorsArray;

}
```